# Can't get the Scope_identity from SQL Server procedure in ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project that require execution of a stored procedure in the controller.

The code in the controller looks like this:

```
var dateAdd = DateTime.Now;
var dateUpdate = DateTime.Now;
var statues = false;

ObjectParameter id = new ObjectParameter("id", typeof(Int32));
var customer = saleOrder.Customer_Id;

var saleorder_id = db.InsertSalesOrder(dateAdd,dateUpdate,saleOrder.Customer_Id , statues);

foreach (var item in list)
{
    db.InsertListItems(item.Item_Id, saleOrder.SalesOrder_id, item.NumberOfItemsInOrder);
}

db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

and the stored procedure is this :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertSalesOrder]
    (@DateAdd datetime, 
     @DateUpdate datetime, 
     @Customer_Id int, 
     @Statues bit)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SaleOrder ([DateAdd], [DateUpdate], [Customer_id], [statues])
        SELECT @DateAdd, @DateUpdate, @Customer_Id, @Statues 

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
END
```

The procedure is returning the id correctly, but the variable does not store the id - it stores something like an object parameter.

Please help me I've been stuck on this for hours

Comment: You need to select the scope_identity into an output variable.

Comment: i tried that but iam facing problems when passing the result to the object parameter the value of the object parameter is still null after the stored procedure executed

Comment: Try `RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: By convention, the value RETURNED by a stored procedure is used to indicate success / failure. Returning the identity value from an insert operation is better accomplished as either a resultset (as already implemented) or as an output parameter.

Comment: @Smore You're absolutely correct. His code is trying to use a return value so I thought I would pose a simple solution in comments.